# How do I rig this "skirt" properly?

Tags: rigging

I've made a character, a fantasy knight, and now I want to animate him.
To do this, I've made my own rig, but it's the first time I need to rig hanging clothes.
Let us call that his skirt, since I can't think of a more appropriate word.

The purpose is to get the skirt out of the way when the character moves his legs forward, but also on the sides.

I thought of using correction bones all around with drivers, and I can make him walk correctly.  But it becomes painful when I try to make it work on the sides as well or if the knee is too high.
I want him to be capable of sitting on horseback without the leg clipping through the skirt. I've been trying to solve that matter for 2 days now, and I still have no idea if it's the right way to do it or if I'm just torturing myself. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using physics, and doing a damped + locked track of vertex groups on a physics mesh, then baking the transforms?

Comment: @Nathan not really, I've only used Blender's physics to animate a chain so far. I've had this idea when I saw a video : 
https://www.twitch.tv/videos/369212754?lang=fr
He explains that at 9mn. He is using another software though and I didn't know how to translate it into Blender, so I thought I could do it with bones. 
Is that the process you are talking about?

Comment: Uhh, kinda.  That's not Blender though.  A lot of what he's talking about isn't really something you can do in Blender (not without some extra work.)  You should consider physics, but it's going to be a decent amount to learn-- not 100% explainable in a single SE answer.  The fastest solution, for a few actions on a single model, without learning anything, is to animate them manually.